# Why doesn't my Flash Control Register update when I write to it (STM32)?

Tags: memory, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, flash-memory

I'm trying to write to update my engineering bytes on the STM32G0 and I'm getting stuck. I need to unlock flash by writing to the FLASH_KEYR register. The manual says this:

```
After reset, write into the FLASH control register (FLASH_CR) is not allowed so as to protect the Flash memory against possible unwanted operations due, for example, to electric disturbances. The following sequence unlocks these registers:

1. Write KEY1 = 0x4567 0123 in the FLASH key register (FLASH_KEYR)
2. Write KEY2 = 0xCDEF 89AB in the FLASH key register (FLASH_KEYR).

Any wrong sequence will lock the FLASH_CR registers until the next system reset. In the case of a wrong key sequence, a bus error is detected and a Hard Fault interrupt is generated.
The FLASH_CR registers can be locked again by software by setting the LOCK bit in one of these registers.

Note: The FLASH_CR register cannot be written when the BSY1 bit of the FLASH status register (FLASH_SR) is set. Any attempt to write to this register with the BSY1 bit set causes the AHB bus to stall until the BSY1 bit is cleared.
```

I making sure that my BSY1 bit is clear when I'm trying to write and I believe that's the only condition.

This is how I'm writing:

```c
#define KEY1  0x45670123
#define KEY2  0xCDEF89AB

... 

FLASH->KEYR = KEY1;
FLASH->KEYR = KEY2;
```

After this point, my FLASH_KEYR register is still 0x0. Does anyone know why?

Edit: here's my code

```c
#define TEST_FLASH_BYTES    ((uint32_t)0x0801FF00)
...

FLASH->CR &= FLASH_CR_LOCK;
FLASH->KEYR = KEY1;
FLASH->KEYR = KEY2;

while(__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_SR_BSY1) != 0) {}

program_flash(TEST_FLASH_BYTES, 0x1234567887654321);

while (__HAL_FLASH_GET_FLAG(FLASH_SR_BSY1) != 0) {}

FLASH->SR &= FLASH_SR_EOP;
FLASH->CR &= FLASH_CR_PG;
```

here is `program_flash`:

```c
static void program_flash(uint32_t address, uint64_t data)
{
    *(uint32_t *)address = (uint32_t)data;

    (independently of compiler optimization behavior) */
    __ISB();

    *(uint32_t *)(address + 4U) = (uint32_t)(data >> 32U);
}
```

Edit: it's a write only register so that's why I can't read it back. I figured out how to write to my memory successfully.

Comment: FLASH_CR default value is 0x0000 0080.Bit 7 is reset by hardware after detecting unlock sequence. So expected value is 0x00.

Comment: @Babajan Where did you see that the default val is 0x0000 0080? The address offset is 0x008 and its reset value is 0x0000 0000 but I'm not sure where that default value came from.

Comment: Default register value is  0x8000 0000 .
Here is a link  https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/cd00233952-stm32f205-215-stm32f207-217-flash-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf   Refer Chapter 2.8.5

Comment: @Babajan that's for the STM32F series

Answer (score 1):

This code enables the boot0 pin to work like a legacy stm32 chip.

```
    //enable BOOT0 pin
    while(GET32(0x40022010)&0x10000) continue;
    PUT32(0x40022008,0x45670123);
    PUT32(0x40022008,0xCDEF89AB);
    PUT32(0x4002200C,0x08192A3B);
    PUT32(0x4002200C,0x4C5D6E7F);
//from the manual:
//ST production value: 0xDFFF E1AA
    PUT32(0x40022020,0xDEFFE1AA);
    while(GET32(0x40022010)&0x10000) continue;
    PUT32(0x40022014,0x00020000);
    while(GET32(0x40022010)&0x10000) continue;
```

PUT32  does an str instruction and GET32 does an ldr instruction.

The different STM32G0 have different default values for some of these registers, the one I have open right now for the FLASH_CR register is:

```
Reset value: 0xC000 0000
```

which is the two lock bit, so each of the unlock sequences above are tied to one bit, so do both sequences and in theory both bits unlock.  May dig out a board/chip and try this and edit this answer to confirm.

It looks like you are doing this from a program, these chips are quite picky, with the flash erased (as in a new chip) you get one shot at the bootloader approach to loading, once something is there, then you can come in through SWD (I assume there is a way to block that), but you can't use swd to write these registers to perform these kinds of tasks you have to run code, and you can run it from ram or flash.

Depending what you are trying to change you may need to power cycle the chip to see the change take effect.

EDIT

```
while(GET32(0x40022010)&0x10000) continue; //need this here?
ra=GET32(0x40022014); //FLASH_CR
while(GET32(0x40022010)&0x10000) continue;
PUT32(0x40022008,0x45670123);
PUT32(0x40022008,0xCDEF89AB);
rb=GET32(0x40022014); //FLASH_CR
PUT32(0x4002200C,0x08192A3B);
PUT32(0x4002200C,0x4C5D6E7F);
rc=GET32(0x40022014); //FLASH_CR
hexstring(ra);
hexstring(rb);
hexstring(rc);
```

uart output

```
C0000000 
40000000 
00000000
```

Which as expected from the documentation.

How and when are you reading the register?  Are you touching any registers in between unlock and read?

Comment: using addresses and magic numbers makes no sense at all. This "pseudo code" also.

Comment: *`which is the two lock bit`* the second one is not relevant as it locks **OPTION BYTES** not related to OPs problem

Comment: @P__J__ there is not one single magic number in that code  FLASH_CR is magic yes you have to dig through layers of code to find out what it is, but this is 100% from the documentation, zero magic, zero mystery, trivial to follow.

Comment: The OP is reading zero, to get to zero you need to clear both bits per the documentation this demonstrates the path to zero as well as before unlocking anything, unlocking one thing then unlocking the other thing.  OPTION BYTES is related to reading a zero (or doesnt have the right address due to magic hidden headers, etc)

Comment: OP is reading zero because he has not enabled FLASH peripheral. It is not FLASH memory only digital interface which is used to program and set FLASH memory. Otherwise he would read the default value of this register with the LOCK bit reset not zero. BTW to read the value you do not need to unlock it.

Comment: Unlocking Option Bytes without the need is a bad practice. You can not intensionally set read protection or other harmful option

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not enable the digital FLASH interface, this is how it needs to be done:

```c
RCC -> AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_FLASHEN;
```

After that, wait for the FLASH peripheral to be ready,

```c
while (FLASH -> SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1);
```

Complete Code-block:

```c
RCC -> AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_FLASHEN;
(*void)RCC -> AHBENR; // readback instead of delay to let this change to propagate throughout the bus.

while(FLASH -> SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1));
//FLASH->CR &= FLASH_CR_LOCK; this line is wrong. First of all, it is not the way of resetting the bits, secondly this bit is SET ONLY which means that you can set it to enable the lock again.

FLASH->KEYR = KEY1;
FLASH->KEYR = KEY2;

while(FLASH -> SR & FLASH_SR_BSY1));
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please dont use hidden values, use values as shown in the documentation.  this question is about documentation not about magic hidden values in some library.

Comment: @old_timer they are not magic numbers. Those definitions are supplied by STM (and it is not the library only the header file with human readable similar to used in the STM documentation definitions). And the code is easy to read. `RCC` is the peripheral and its register called `AHBENR`. You need to set the bit `FLASHEN` in this register. So the definition is `RCC_AHBENR_FLASHEN`. `*(volatile uint32_t *)0x40005678 |= 0x00010000` is rather hard to decode for people.

Comment: @P__J__ why does setting `RCC -> AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_FLASHEN;` help with unlocking flash? I tried adding it and it didn't change anything

Comment: Because it enables the FLASH interface clock. After this you should read the default value of the  FLASH -> CR register. If you still read zero it means you made somewhere else mistake and I am unable to help you without seeing the full code.

Comment: @P__J__ I just added the full code to my question :)

Comment: @rt134134 you need to learn bitwise operations and need to read carefully the documentaion.

Comment: @P__J__ are you implying that there's something wrong with my code?

Comment: @P__J__ I realized that it's a write only register but my code still doesn't work to write to the register I want

Comment: @rt134134 what does (n your opinion) this line do? : `FLASH->CR &= FLASH_CR_LOCK;`

Comment: @P__J__ I know that's a write only register so it doesn't do anything. I don't think that's the issue though

Comment: @rt134134 abstracting form that. what does this statement do ? `var1 &= 0x100;`

Comment: @rt134134 No, it does not.  You need to learn basic bitwise operators. In this case it clears **all bits** except the 8th. To clear the 8th bit you need to `var1 &= ~0x100;`  same here: `FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_LOCK;`